# How include a sub menu in my main menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I'm a undergraduate student and I'm making a website for project.

Now, I'm making the "Mobile version", adding media-queries to my website and I want to make a Hamburger menu. 
In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCM5G.jpg) is what I did till now.

I want to put a link to menu tab,so when I pressed the "Menu" tab,the website will jump to another div(a new menu with new tabs).

With few words, I want to change it in a multi-menu.

I'm sorry for my English, I tried the best with my syntax.

I can't use JQuery at all..

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```css
#menu {  visibility: hidden; }

#DropMobile {  display: none; }

label {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background:  rgba(229,229,229,0.88);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s;
  z-index: 10;
}

label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(229,229,229,0.88);
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  z-index: 99;
}

label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(229,229,229,0.88);
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}

label div {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: display 5s ease-in-out;
}

label div nav ul {  margin-top: 25%; padding: 0;  list-style-type: none;}

label div nav ul li {  margin: 5% 0;  text-align: center;}

label div nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(229,229,229,0.9);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu:checked + label {  width: 0;}

#menu:checked + label div {
  display: block;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

#menu:checked + label:before {
  background: rgba(229,229,229,0.88);;
  transform: rotate(38deg) translate(0px);
}

#menu:checked + label:after {
  background: rgba(229,229,229,0.88);;
  transform: rotate(-38deg) translate(0px);
}
```

```html
<header id="MenuMobile">
 <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
 <label for="menu">
  <div>
   <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>  
     <li> <a> Menu </a>    
     <li> <a href="reservation.php">Reservation</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="about.html">About Us</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="contact.php">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
   </nav> 
  </div>
 </label>
</header>
```

Comment: So, you'd like to have another complete menu with different content display in this same area with the click of a link?

Comment: yes exactly, with the same design

Comment: Gotcha.  Would this be using an element inside the current menu, like a clickable arrow floating to the right like a slider in a carousel?  Or just a plain text link to show the additional menu?

Comment: i want  to change the text and put my sub menu, if you can show me a way to put a clickable arrow to go back to main menu, is gonna be great.

Comment: Doing this without the help of jquery is going to be a bit of a challenge but I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: I can still use JavaScript, but it's hard for me..I'll try it later again.. thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, I was assuming that you're required not to use jquery as this might be an assignment or something.